# Get result on two table join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I have a criteria where i want to join table 1 with table 2 , table 1 consists of products which were given to salesman to sell and table 2 has the sales data which salesman has sold out.
Now i want to know left over products of each sales with join.
Below is my data, here is what i am trying to do, but it return only salesman 1 data.
I need help to join these tables as per my requirement

```
CREATE TABLE Salesman_Product
(

SalesManID int,
ProductID int

)

INSERT INTO Salesman_Product (SalesManID,ProductID) Values (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)  
INSERT INTO Salesman_Product (SalesManID,ProductID) Values (2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4) 

--select * from Salesman_Product

CREATE TABLE Salesman_Sales
(

SalesManID int,
ProductID int,
Status varchar(3)

)


INSERT INTO Salesman_Sales (SalesManID,ProductID,Status) Values (1,1,'Yes'),(1,3,'Yes') 
INSERT INTO Salesman_Sales (SalesManID,ProductID,Status) Values (2,1,'Yes'),(2,2,'Yes'),(2,3,'Yes')

--select * from Salesman_Sales 

;WITH CTE_RES AS
(
SELECT * FROM Salesman_Product
WHERE ProductID NOT IN
(
SELECT Salesman_Sales.ProductID FROM Salesman_Sales INNER JOIN
Salesman_Product ON
Salesman_Sales.SalesManID =Salesman_Product.SalesManID
AND Salesman_Sales.ProductID =Salesman_Product.ProductID
--AND Salesman_Sales.SalesManID =1
)
)
SELECT * INTO #TEMP_RES FROM CTE_RES
SELECT * FROM #TEMP_RES
--DROP TABLE #TEMP_RES
```

required result

```
SALESMANID   PRODUCTID
1            2
1            4
2            4
```

Comment: What does `Status` mean in your Salesman_Sales table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over complicating what should be a simple select with `not exists`:

```
SELECT SalesManID, ProductID
FROM Salesman_Product p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM  Salesman_Sales s 
   WHERE p.SalesManID = s.SalesManID and p.ProductID = s.ProductID
)
```

Results:

```
SalesManID    ProductID
1             2
1             4
2             4
```

[see fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8af01/4)